# Why does Go use its own Code generator?

Tags: code-generation, go, elf

The current, official compiler for Go (http://code.google.com/p/go/) currently uses a handcrafted, arguably arcane code generator, which includes injecting custom sections into the ELF Binary.

This approach has spawned quite a few bugs related to utilities that directly read and/or write ELF Information, such as `ldd`, `objdump` or `strip`.

I believe that this could have been prevented by using a welltested crossplatform code generator, such as LLVM, and then just use linking facilities shipped with the OS, such as `ld` on Unix/Linux (or `ld.exe` on windows w/ MinGW), or `link.exe` on Windows with Visual Studio.

So why does Go use its very own code generator? Is it really just reinventing the wheel? Or are there more important reasons behind it?

Comment: You'd have to ask someone on that project why they made that choice.

Comment: To have complete control of what they do.

Comment: @dmckee: Or you could read their answer to this question.

Comment: Compiling speed was one of the main design points. So they couldn't rely on the huge and very slow LLVM or GCC backends. But later they made versions of the GO compiler which use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For information on how to use gccgo, a more traditional compiler using the GCC back end, see [Setting up and using gccgo](http://golang.org/doc/gccgo_install.html).

The [Go Language Specification](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html) is compiler agnostic. You can choose from the available compilers, write one yourself, or contribute to the [LLVM Go frontend](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/b645ef10d1cff11b) project.

For an historical perspective on the Go compiler technology, read the answer to this question: [What compiler technology is used to build the compilers?](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#What_compiler_technology_is_used_to_build_the_compilers)

Answer (score 3):

The reference compiler (5g, 6g, and 8g, collectively referred to as gc) was written by Ken Thompson based on the C compiler he wrote for the Plan 9 operating system. There are a couple reasons he did this:

- He was already familiar with how his C compiler worked, so it was easier for him to adapt his existing work rather than learning an entirely new framework.
- One of Go's goals is to compile fast. The gc compiler is probably faster than an LLVM-based compiler could be because it's just not doing as much work. Then again, it's also not optimizing as well.

As Peter mentioned, there's also gccgo, which uses gcc as a backend. I suspect there will eventually be other options for Go compilers, especially given that the Go libraries include a complete Go parser and a (partially complete) type checker.